# regex pattern matcher fails

Tags: java, regex

I want to know why my regex pattern matcher below fails.

I have included `?A-Za-z0-9` to include chars and numbers

`System.out.print(Pattern.compile("[?A-Za-z0-9]").matcher("aa22Aa?").matches());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?A-Za-z0-9` will only match a single occurrence of a particular character defined in the set

You need to add `+` quantifier to the pattern so that one or more of the characters match

```
[?A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Instead of calling `.compile()` function to compile the pattern and then calling `.matcher()` function to create a `Matcher`, you can use `.matches()` function of `Pattern` class to compile the pattern and match it with the string.

```
System.out.print(Pattern.matches("[?A-Za-z0-9]+", "aa22Aa?"));
```

#### Edit:

As rightly pointed out by @Andreas, you could also use `.matches()` function of `String` class

```
System.out.print("aa22Aa?".matches("[?A-Za-z0-9]+"));
```

Comment: Why not [`"aa22Aa?".matches("[?A-Za-z0-9]+")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: @Andreas completely forgot about that function. Thank you for commenting that. Included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"[?A-Za-z0-9]+"`.